# django-import-export syncdb issue

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-settings, django-import-export

I'm trying to set up django-import-export on my Django site. I've already run `pip freeze` so I know it's in my directory, but when I tried `python3 manage.py syncdb` I got this error:

```
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'import_export'
```

I'm not sure what could be the issue, since import-export is already in INSTALLED_APPS as 'import_export'.
Help for a first time Django developer?
Thanks!

Comment: just to check: A) if you do ./manage.py shell, can you import import_export? B) same from straight python3 shell C) do you have python2 and python3 installed?  I seem to recall having pip3 versus pip and so it's possible you installed it to your python2 repo if you have both

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying so fast! I re-installed using pip3 and now my error is different. `$ python3 manage.py syncdb
Unknown command: 'syncdb'`

Comment: Hmm... that's odd.  If you do python3 manage.py help, do you get other options (and which django are you running?  I thought django was deprecating syncdb, but that still should come back with a warning versus not found)

Comment: (and actually, apparently I'm behind on django-latest; django 1.9.4 does in fact just not support syncdb; try doing python3 manage.py migrate instead)